# Will I be able to get retweet/likes notifications from ones who turn off my retweet?

Tags: twitter, notifications, retweet

I'm conscious that, if ones turn off my retweets, will I be able to get the the notification if they still retweet me, like if they still follow my twitter account or if they added me to their list.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you will get notifications from that user whenever (s)he retweet or favorite your tweets.

Turning off your retweets doesn't affect to notification on your tweets.